# High Vulnerability Detected in Dependency (NPM inflight) of mocha

Tags: mocha.js, glob, checkmarx, npm-vulnerabilities

How to Remediate: Vulnerability Detected in inflight package (Missing Release of Resource after Effective Lifetime)

I recently ran a security scan using Checkmarx One and detected a high vulnerability in the npm inflight package (version 1.0.6).

**Package**: inflight

**Version**: 1.0.6 (latest)

**CWE**: CWE-722 (Missing Release of Resource after Effective Lifetime)

**Description**: In NPM inflight there is a Memory Leak because some resources are not freed correctly after being used. It appears to affect all versions, as the issue was not addressed and no fix is found. NOTE: In the meantime, logdna-agent, a package that depends on inflight, has merged a commit to address this solely in their package (so it should be fixed in logdna-agent in versions 1.6.5 and later). Node-glob, a package that also depends on inflight, was also planning to address this by not using inflight after version 8 is released, but it is still being used.

I did not directly install and use the inflight package. It is a dependency of the package that I am currently using which is mocha @ 10.2.0.

[Screenshot of Checkmarx One description of the vulnerability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTtc3.png)

Is there any recommended remediation for this vulnerability?

Comment: Did you get a fix for this???